# How to make an :even declaration more specific

Tags: jquery

I am wondering how I might make this script more specific. I am thinking that attaching an ID to specify the particular container would would work. How can that be done with the script?

Current state of script:

```
$('tr:even').addClass('table-alt');
```

Would this work?

```
$('#myDiv tr:even').addClass('table-alt');
```

Comment: Specific in what sense? It's selectors is the same as CSS, so we can pinpoint any element on the page

Comment: thanks for responding, the script was intended to function with one table specifically. This script will affect ALL tables i believe.

Answer (score 1):

It will work assuming you have element with ID `myDiv` that contains table rows. If you don't have such element in the HTML it won't work.